# CLR gui for VS2010 MSVC / VC++ double to String, String to double methods for EditText Textboxes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc, clr

CLR gui for VS2010 MSVC / VC++ 
double to String, 
String to double methods for getting in and out of EditText Textboxes?

I've found a few examples for MFC but that is older and the double to Text conversion is built-in
any examples for CLR including the convert methods?

Are there any good examples for VS2010 C++ gui???

Answer (score 0):

Try

String to Double : `static double dVar =  System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);`  or   `dVar =  System::Double::Parse(textBox1->Text);`.

Double to String : `textbox1->Text = System::Convert::ToString( dVar )`   or  `textbox1->Text = +" "+dVar  +" ";`

The Convert Class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx

Comment: Scott thanks for your reply. I've tried MFC which has the conversion built-in....Now trying CLR and needed the methods....so thanks....Is CLR the best one for gui ?   Not even sure about ATL...

Comment: Windows Forms C++/CLR .NET GUI coding  is so much eaiser than MFC. Not clunky and clumsy like MFC. Its easy, like coding in C# or VB.NET. Very logical.

Comment: Is ATL another gui alternative?  Looks like you recommend CLR then

Comment: ATL is a fast, easy way to create small COM components,     MFC  allows you to create full applications : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8ytxz5(v=vs.80).aspx and here too :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This is not the right way to do it, the code will bomb with an exception when the user typed something wrong.  Use double::TryParse() instead.  And use double::ToString(), you always need a format specifier to create a string that's easy on human eyes.

Comment: Here is the conversion part
CLR isnt too bad... better than MFC yes?

//How to do conversions for CLR C++ GUI

double dblInput1 = 0.0;
double dblInput2 = 0.0;
double dblAnswer = 0.0;
String ^ strInput1;
String ^ strInput2;
strInput1 = this->Input1textBox->Text;
strInput2 = this->Input2textBox->Text;

if (Double::TryParse(strInput1, dblInput1) & Double::TryParse(strInput2, dblInput2))

{

// do something
dblAnswer = dblInput1 + dblInput2;

Answer1textBox->Text = System::Convert::ToString( dblAnswer );
}

else

{
// the text was not a number
MessageBox::Show("Error");
}